# C++ how to implement delete operator to deallocates memory depends on context

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I have a code which is like this

```
std::vector<Snake*>body;
```

and I assign something tu first element of body

```
body.push_back(new Snake(sf::Vector2u(1, 0)));
```

and then when I do not want to use it. I do not know how to delete or free the memory, there seems to be a lot of way to do it. when I tried this.

```
delete body;
```

it gave me error, and I tried another way which is

```
delete &body;
```

it worked, and then I thought that I was using array, so maybe I should delete it with '[]' sign, then I tried to put that sign.

```
delete[] &body;
```

it also worked, but I do not know which one is the correct one, the one without '[]' or the one with '[]'. if there is a link or a post about this that has been answered, please help me to tag it :)

Thank you

Comment: Neither one is correct. You didn't `new` body so you're not supposed to `delete` it. `delete` the snake instead.

Comment: Better yet, use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Snake>>`, or even `std::vector<Snake>` if possible.

Comment: You only need to `delete` what you've `new`ed, so `delete ( body [ 0 ] );` is valid. But you would mainly only used pointers for putting `Snake`s in an array, so I think (because you're already using a vector) you'll make things easier by following @Quentin's advice. When the vector goes out of scope, it and all the `Snake`s in it will be destroyed.